# Accuracy Assessment of NDWI - GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, accuracy, normalized-difference-water-index

I have applied NDWI (Normalized Difference Water Index) on years: 2018, 2019 and 2020 to extract the water bodies. Then I used [MCD12Q1.061 MODIS Land Cover Type Yearly Global 500m](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MCD12Q1#bands) product for the year 2017 only (as a ground truth) and extracted only the water bodies class.

**Goal:**
Now, I want to see the accuracy of NDWI by taking MCD12Q1.061 MODIS Land Cover Type Yearly Global 500m as a ground truth.

My question is, is it possible? If it is, can someone please tell the pipeline/solution?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using that product as ground truth. There are several databases of water bodies to compare. Is the goal identify reservoirs? If so, check this: https://github.com/global-water-watch/research-reservoir-water-dynamics

Comment: @aldo_tapia Yes and I want to see how well the NDWI works. So, I want to compute the accuracy. Can you please suggest if this approach works?

Comment: You need to manually digitalize the water bodies, using MODIS' LULC maps won't work well